# Most general column mapping using python

Tags: python

I have been doing column switching by python using

```
my_array[:,[0, 1]] = my_array[:,[1, 0]]
```

But I need to now make it more general. It should work for multiple columns and multiple maches like '1st column of input.txt becomes 2nd column of output.txt, 3rd col of input becomes 5th col of output...'

I have tried

```
my_array[:,[1,0,4,3,2]] = my_array[:,[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

I might also make a file called col_map.txt and the program should mat columns according to this rule written in col_map.txt

```
col_map.txt
1,2 #1st column of input.txt goes to 2nd column of output.txt
2,1 #2 and 1, respectively
3,5 #3 and 4, respectively
4,4 #4 and 4, respectively, so the position doesn't change
5,3 #5 and 3, respectively
```

But I haven't been able to try this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what you tried you probably forgot on the right-hand side that indices are zero-based. Anyway, with Numpy arrays, try only:

`my_array = my_array[:,[1,0,4,3,2]]`

What are you trying to achieve? Do you work with large input files?
Since you seem to have an "input.txt", you could use the bash commands instead, like `awk`:

`awk '{print $2,$1,$5,$4,$3}' input.txt > output.txt`

You may need to specify the field separators in both input and output:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t";} {print $2,$1,$5,$4,$3}' input.txt > output.txt`

Back to Python, if your input files are big you don't want to load everything in an array but instead read one line at a time, split it, then rewrite the line to the output file after switching the elements (a suggestion is to look at `operator.itemgetter` for items selection).

Comment: Thank you.. but what does `cut` do? I experimented and it changes `1 3 5 6 8` to `1 3 6 8` . It just eliminates 3rd column.

Comment: I am trying to do something like '1st column of input.txt becomes 2nd column of output.txt, 3rd col of input becomes 5th col of output...'

Comment: The last number should have been a 3. Indeed, `cut` does not reorder the columns, sorry. You should use `awk` instead. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you!This `awk` solution is great!  However, I could check that it can't deal with non-English. Is there any way to deal with it?

Comment: The problem is probably the file encoding. You must change it before using awk, or it is possible that it will not recognize "special" characters. I know that using Vim you can `:set ff=unix` and `:set fileencoding=utf-8`. With other editors I don't know. You can find some answers in other posts of this forum though, such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820659/how-to-read-files-with-different-encodings-using-awk

Comment: Changing encoding of input file to UTF-8 solved the problem. Thank you!