# printf in awk with Umlauts doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, awk, character-encoding

Can somebody please give me an alternative to the following awk statement. As soon as I give a "n" for string,  it skips after Umlaut. I don't want to use gsub because I have many special characters and don't want to write a script for this.

```
$ echo "Döll" | awk '{printf "%s\n", $0}'
Döll
$ echo "Döll" | awk '{printf "%1s\n", $0}'
D
```

Also if not in awk, can somebody help me in other languages?

Comment: to me, the 2nd command also returns "Döll". It doesn't happen even if using German: `LANG=De_DE.88591 echo "Döll" | awk '{printf "%1s\n", $0}'`.

Comment: Same result as @fedorqui, second line works like charm.

Comment: en_US.ISO8859-1 with german keyboard, to me as well it returns "Döll" in both cases....

Comment: Are you using a "funny" version of `awk`, an unusual shell, or a defective terminal?

Comment: i am just guessing here but try nawk instead of awk....

Comment: Hi All,Thanks for the hints. My LANG variable was set to en_US.UTF-8. That was the issue. CHanged it to De_DE.88591. Now it works like a charm. Thanks to all esp @fedorqui.

Comment: Nice that you could solve it! Just for the record, to me `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 echo "Döll" | awk '{printf "%1s\n", $0}'` also returns `Döll`.

Comment: @fedorqui That's probably because you copied it from SO, which has UTF-8 encoding whereas tranceporter has typed it in ISO-8859-1. This problem is independent of the language, it's encoding-specific.

Comment: Interesting why for me this does not work `echo "Döll" | awk '(tolower($0) ~ /döll/)'` but this works `echo "Döll" | awk '(tolower($0) ~ /döll/i)'`

Comment: Ok, it's because awk on OSX is not familiar with utf8 looks like, so installing gawk solved the issue :)

Comment: Which AWK implementation? GAWK, NAWK, Solaris AWK? Which locale settings? Which code point(s) (combining characters, the already combined version?)

Comment: I've added a community wiki answer so that this question can be [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and thus marked as answered. Currently, this question is the highest ranked [unanswered bash question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash?sort=unanswered). Ideally, the community wiki answer would also be improved.

Comment: @user1016265 Also note that the awk file itself (or the CLI like awk '{print $0 "äöü"}') has to be in proper encoding, it otherwise may also affect the input data. [duplicate comment of mine, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820659/ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by the `LANG` variable being set to `en_US.UTF-8`. After changing it to `De_DE.88591`, it works like a charm.